# Can't validate Reactive Form with Custom Validator for input (type=['file']) max size

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, custom-validators

In short words, problem is to validate File Upload input for file max size. Angular by default isn't storing anywhere user's attached File object in Form Control. There is only `value` property which contains fake path for file.
Ideal case should be to use Custom Validator for this purpose, but through validator function I can't get attached File object which is storing File's size. I have only access to Form Control object.

Maybe someone got similar problem previously or have any idea which could be helpful?

At the moment I am using manual File object validation on `change` event and manually setting/clearing attachment's errors.

Comment: Found that input's with `type='file'` is a weak spot in Angular forms. https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/3466

Comment: What you're currently doing is what you should be doing, don't worry.

Comment: Then you say, there isn't any better way how to do this validation?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. As the first comment says, `File`s are Angular's weakness.

Comment: You could imagine a better solution, which would be creating your own form control that handles file changes, but why would you if you already got it working ?

Comment: Ohh, that way could not be so great. :) Just wanted to know, how to do this with Custom Validators which is a best practice in Angular how to validate not standard things for form inputs, but looks like it's not possible yet.

Comment: You don't have to rely on custom validators, you can validate, then set errors on your input.

Comment: Ok, then my current solution is fine. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in comments, found that input's with type='file' is a weak spot in Angular forms - github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/3466 and decided to go with my described solution with manual File object validation on change event and manually setting/clearing attachment's errors.